# django - view that creates or updates a model but requires a submit

Tags: django, django-models

I have class based modelview where I want the model/instance to be created or updated.  If updating, I want the fields to show their current values.  I have this working except that the instance is being created just by loading the view/template. As soon as the page loads, the object is saved. I think it's very important that the save is not done until the submit button is clicked.

I also want to override the model's save() method because I need to check what field is being updated and update a different model/object.

**Model**

```
class GradeBookSetup(DirtyFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=CASCADE)
    level1 = models.IntegerField(default=55)
    scale_mode = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, default="VSB")
    teacher_show_sec_percent = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GradeBookSetup, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'scale_mode' in dirty_fields:
            objs = Grade.objects.filter(user=self.user)
            n = 0
            for grade in objs:
                 objs[n].score = "BEG"
```

**View**

```
@method_decorator([login_required], name='dispatch')
class GradeBookSetupCreateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = GradeBookSetupForm
    model = GradeBookSetup

    success_url = "/gradebook/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj, created = GradeBookSetup.objects.get_or_create(
            user=self.request.user)
        return obj
```

**Form**

```
class GradeBookSetupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = GradeBookSetup
        fields = ['level1', 'scale_mode', 'teacher_show_sec_percent']
        labels = {
            "level1": "What percent?",
            "scale_mode": "Choose your proficiency scale.",
            'teacher_show_sec_percent': "Teacher view (10-12), show percent",
        }
```

**EDIT**
My next try is to move the `get_or_create` into the `form_valid` method as suggested by [hendrikschneider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68785928/4618992). I still need to get the object to display the correct values after the initial save so I mean to do this with the `try:`. I had to change the `get_or_create` to `update_or_create`.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.instance, created = GradeBookSetup.objects.update_or_create(
        user=self.request.user, defaults={'scale_mode':form.instance.scale_mode})
    return super().form_valid(form)

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    try:
        obj = GradeBookSetup.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return obj
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your get_object method. The method is called when a get and when a post request is executed. As you use get_or_create there, it is always executed. Make sure that you only get_or_create in your form_valid method and not in get_object.

Comment: I think I understand your solution and tried to implement it with the EDIT shown in my question.  The object is saved but only with the default values.

Comment: In the def form_valid method I changed from get_or_create to update_or_create, since the get_object method already checked for the get condition.